# Pass Query parameters from apex controller to JS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller

How do I pass apex query parameters to a third party url onclick in Lightning

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccount()
    {
        Account a = [SELECT Id,name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
        return a;
    }
```

**cmp:**

```
 <a click"{!c.Entersite}">Enter the site</a>
```

**JS Controller**

```
 Entersite: function (component, event, helper) {
 //I want something like www.google.com?id=accountid&Name=accountname
});
```

Comment: are you trying to hit a url and trying to a get response?

Comment: No I just need to redirect to that particular URL

Comment: have tried `window.location.href="https://www.google.com"`?

Comment: should I do that within the JS controller? and how do I pass the accountid and name values?

Comment: you have to call the @auraenabled method from the component's controller.js and get the accountid and name values.With that said, where are using the component, is it inside `one/one.app` or standalone app(eg:myappname.app)

Comment: It is a stanalone app and I'm trying to understand on how do I convert the JSON object to get the Id and the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46169/discussion-between-praveen-and-cartman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your @AuraEnabled method returns Account instance(you mentioned you would limit it to 1) which contains Name and Id.

Once you get the response, it will be an JSON Object, which can be retrieved by calling the `getReturnValue()`.

```
{
    "Name":"Test Account",
    "Id":"001XXXXXXX"
}
```

Since above is an JS Object, you could the values of using **.** notation. Also make sure you are trying to use the field's API correctly, since everything in lightning is case-sensitive.

```
Entersite : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            if (component.isValid() && response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                window.location.href = "https:\\www.google.com?id="+response.Id+"&Name="+response.Name;
            }
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

**NOTE** : Also for every async callback's it is recommend to check if the component exist by doing `component.isValid()`